# Regular expression word to match text that includes a word ending in 'ing' but does exclude the words anything, something, nothing

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, regex-lookarounds

I am coding an app to practice English, I need a javascript regular expression to find all the docs in a mongoDb collection on which the 'answer' property contains a word that ends in **ing** and exclude a few words from the match like everything, something, anything, nothing.

I have the following query right now:

```
{ '$or': [ { answer: /ing/i } ],
I20190303-13:26:00.915(-4)?   answer: /^(?!.*(\bsomething\b|\banything\b|\beverything\b|\bthing\b|\bnothing\b))/gi }
```

Unfortunately, my current query excludes strings like: **'I am doing nothing.'** because nothing is in the text. But I would like texts like this to match because doing is present.

I want to get all the questions from the database whose answer contains one or more gerunds, unfortunately there are words that end in **ing** that are not gerunds.

Comment: Good question.  SUGGESTION (it's something you could easily do in "sed" or "awk"): 1) do a "text substitution" to ELIMINATE the words "something", "anything",etc. from the search string, 2) then - and only then - search the modified string for "ing".

Answer (score 1):

[Negative Lookbehind](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookbehind-assertions.php) should work.

```
db.collection.find({
  "key": {
    $regex: "(?<!noth|anyth)ing",  //match ing, but not if it is part of nothing, anything
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ypfDCki-EI4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to find all documents in a MongoDB collection where the 'answer' property contains a word that ends in "ing" and exclude a few words like "everything", "som

```
/\b(?!(everything|something|anything|nothing)\b)\w+ing\b/gi
```

I hope this will solve your problem.